# http GET using proxy - Curl command works but python "requests" library does not

Tags: python, python-2.7, http, curl, python-requests

I have the following working curl command:

```
curl -x http://<PROXY URL>:3128 -u myUsername 'https://logs.company.net/daily-2017.04.13/_search?pretty' -d '{BIG JSON BLOB}
```

I am trying to convert that into python using the requests library. Here is what I have so far:

```
json_string = '''{BIG JSON BLOB}'''

print(json_string)
mydict = json.loads(json_string)    # obj now contains a dict of the data

proxies = {"http" : "http://<proxy url>:3128"}
r = requests.get("https://logs.company.net/daily-2017.04.13/_search?pretty", data=json_string,auth=(self.username, self.password), proxies=proxies, verify= False) #
print(r.status_code, r.reason)
print(str(r.content))
```

From what I understand this is basically identical to the above, but it times out on my test server when the curl command does not.

Does anyone know what the problem is here or how I can debug it? I could have hacked in the curl command using the subprocess module but I am pretty new to debugging networking stuff and I want to learn why it is not working hence deciding to ask here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual page of [curl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) command, the `-d` flag is used to post data using the POST request:

> -d/--data
>
> (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a **POST** request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the data to the server using the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Compare to -F/--form.

So, you need to use `requests.post()` function instead of `requests.get()`.

For instance:

```
r = requests.post("https://logs.company.net/daily-2017.04.13/_search?pretty",
                  data=json_string,
                  auth=(self.username, self.password),
                  proxies=proxies,
                  verify=False)
```

Comment: Thanks Laurent I was a bit confused about that as I have seen examples online where data is still sent using get(). Unfortunately changing that still results in a timeout though.

Comment: @OnMyWayToGodDontKnow: do you have a timeout on with the proxy or with the remote server?

Comment: Timeout to the proxy. I'm wondering if it might be something related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8816739/2765131