# Requests - proxies dictionary

Tags: python, proxy, network-programming, connection, python-requests

I'm little confused about `requests` module, especially **proxies**.

From documentation:

**PROXIES**

> Dictionary mapping protocol to the URL of the proxy (e.g. {‘http’:
>   ‘foo.bar:3128’}) to be used on each Request.

May there be more proxies of one type in the dictionary? I mean is it possible to put there list of proxies and `requests` module will try them and use only those which are working?

Or there can be only one proxy address for example for `http`?

Comment: seen [this SO QA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369598/python-how-to-use-requests-library-to-access-a-url-through-several-different-pr) yet? From it, it sounds like it's possible to have multiple proxies for a single protocol. Try!

Comment: Seems only one proxy is valid for one protocol. You may have to check the availability of proxies by yourself.

Comment: proxies in requests are very crappy imho ... especially if the user is behind a proxyconfigfile and other nonsense

Comment: OK, I have tried myself. Obviously it works because multiple keys in the dictionary are overwritten and only the last entry is considered.

Comment: @Pynchia So it doesn't work, does it? I was thinking about something like 'http':[ip,ip,ip..]

Comment: please see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `proxies` parameter is limited by the very nature of a python dictionary (i.e. each key must be unique).

```
import requests

url = 'http://google.com'
proxies = {'https': '84.22.41.1:3128',
           'http': '185.26.183.14:80',
           'http': '178.33.230.114:3128'}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print url
    print proxies
    response = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print response.text
    else:
        print 'Response ERROR', response.status_code
```

outputs

```
http://google.com
{'http': '178.33.230.114:3128', 'https': '84.22.41.1:3128'}
<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en"><head><meta content="Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking for."
...more html...
```

As you can see, the value of the `http` protocol key in the `proxies` dictionary corresponds to the last encountered in its assignment (i.e. `178.33.230.114:3128`). Try swapping the `http` entries around.

So, the answer is no, you cannot specify multiple proxies for the same protocol using a simple dictionary.

I have tried using an iterable as a value, which would make sense to me

```
proxies = {'https': '84.22.41.1:3128',
           'http': ('178.33.230.114:3128', '185.26.183.14:80', )}
```

but with no luck, it produces an error

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I've tried many proxies but it seems that there is some problem. r = requests.get('https://wtfismyip.com/text', proxies={'http':'52.10.202.111:8080'}) returns my ip address instead of this proxy which is Anonymous proxy.

Comment: you have a typo in the `get` call (`;`). I have tried with the proxies in my answer a few minutes ago and they work fine. I got the proxies from [this site](http://www.cool-proxy.net/proxies/http_proxy_list/sort:score/direction:desc). Does my answer satisfy your question?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I didn't noticed that wtfismyip is a https instead of http. Now, everything works correctly :)

Comment: And yes, your answer satisfied my question. Thank you

Comment: Thank you, I have learnt something new today, thanks to your question. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually you can, I've done this with a few lines of code and it works pretty well.

```
import requests


class Client:

    def __init__(self):
        self._session = requests.Session()
        self.proxies = None

    def set_proxy_pool(self, proxies, auth=None, https=True):
        """Randomly choose a proxy for every GET/POST request        
        :param proxies: list of proxies, like ["ip1:port1", "ip2:port2"]
        :param auth: if proxy needs auth
        :param https: default is True, pass False if you don't need https proxy
        """
        from random import choice

        if https:
            self.proxies = [{'http': p, 'https': p} for p in proxies]
        else:
            self.proxies = [{'http': p} for p in proxies]

        def get_with_random_proxy(url, **kwargs):
            proxy = choice(self.proxies)
            kwargs['proxies'] = proxy
            if auth:
                kwargs['auth'] = auth
            return self._session.original_get(url, **kwargs)

        def post_with_random_proxy(url, *args, **kwargs):
            proxy = choice(self.proxies)
            kwargs['proxies'] = proxy
            if auth:
                kwargs['auth'] = auth
            return self._session.original_post(url, *args, **kwargs)

        self._session.original_get = self._session.get
        self._session.get = get_with_random_proxy
        self._session.original_post = self._session.post
        self._session.post = post_with_random_proxy

    def remove_proxy_pool(self):
        self.proxies = None
        self._session.get = self._session.original_get
        self._session.post = self._session.original_post
        del self._session.original_get
        del self._session.original_post

    # You can define whatever operations using self._session
```

I use it like this:

```
client = Client()
client.set_proxy_pool(['112.25.41.136', '180.97.29.57'])
```

It's simple, but actually works for me.