# Is there a way to emulate cURL's -U : option in the Python Requests Library

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, ntlm

Some of you might have seen my previous post as to using PycURL but I've wanted to move back to Requests because I find it an easier library to use. However at the moment I'm hitting a stumbling block due to the NTLM authentication I'm being forced to use.

At the moment, in cURL, if you use the option -U : when performing a request it will send the credentials from the current logged in Windows environment to the server you're executing the request on. Since this small utility I'm writing is going to have to be automated it's not practical to get a user to type in a password for every request so my question would be is there a way to emulate this -U : option in Python's Requests Library? I know about the [requests-ntlm](https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm/) project but that still requires you to prime the object with a log in and password whereas the cURL solution doesn't require this.

Perhaps as a starter would someone be able to explain something of how the option actually works and whether there were any other tools that could emulate it since I don't have any problems using more third party libraries, I'd just like something that would work.

Answer (score -1):

From curl's man page :

> -U, --proxy-user    Specify  the user name and
>   password to use for proxy authentica-   tion.
>
> If you use an SSPI-enabled curl binary and do  NTLM  authentica-
>   tion,  you  can force curl to pick up the user name and password
>   from your environment by simply specifying a single  colon  with
>   this option: "-U :".
>
> If this option is used several times, the last one will be used.

So then you can use proxies dict when performing a request. More details here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8287752/299499 and the requests docs on which the answer from link is based : http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#module-requests .