# python requests module proxy handler not working

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I am using python request module for doing HTTP communications. I was using proxy before doing any communication.

```
import requests

proxy = {'http': 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port'}

                   OR

proxy = {'http': 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port'}

                  OR

proxy = {'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port'}


requests.get(url, proxies = proxy)
```

I am using the above code to add the proxy to the request object. But its seems like proxy is not working. Requests module is taking my network IP and firing the request.

Are there any bug or issue with the request module or any other know issue or is there anything i am missing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proxies with Python 'Requests' module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287628/proxies-with-python-requests-module)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
proxy = {'http': 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port'}
```

I guess you just missed the `http://` in the value of the proxy dict. 
Check: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies

Comment: Does the proxy need username/pawssword?

Comment: No proxy does not have any username. I think i got the issue. Requests in python does not support for https. It only supports for http proxies. If you try using https it will not use the proxy instead it will use your local IP address for the request.

Comment: What? requests supports https for sure.

Comment: I tried it using proxy = {'https': 'https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port'} but it didn't worked it internally called my original IP. If i modify it to proxy = {'http': 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port'} then it started working for me.

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies) says:

> If you need to use a proxy, you can configure individual requests with
>   the proxies argument to any request method:

```
import requests
proxies = {"http": "http://10.10.1.10:3128"}
requests.get("http://example.org", proxies=proxies)
```

Here proxies["http"] = "`http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port`". It seems you lack **http://**