# Does urllib.getproxies work with https websites?

Tags: python, https, request, proxies

I am trying to use proxies to scrape some informations off a website, however I have heard that urlib.getProxies() doesn't work, especially for https websites.Here is my code:

```
page = requests.get(url,proxies = urllib.getproxies())
```

So does this actually work and is there a way to find out if it is requesting through proxies, instead of my ip address.By the way I am requesting a https website. Thanks for your help ahead of time.

Comment: Have you tried it to see if it works?

Comment: @will The request works, it's just that how do I make sure that it is using a proxy instead of my iP address?

Answer (score 1):

[this question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8287628/432913) explains exactly what your problem might be.

The proxyDict you're supplying to `requests.get(... proxies = X)` needs to have a proxy set for the specific protocol of the request you're making. That is, if you're making an `https` requests, you need to have `proxyDict["https"]` set to something.

What does `urllib.getproxies()` return for you? Is there anything set for the `https` protocol?