# perform a google search and return the number of results

Tags: python, python-2.7, http

The Google Web Search APIs appear to be dead (both the old SOAP and the newer AJAX).  Is there a quick way to search Google for a string and return the number of results?  I assume I just have to run the search and scrape the results, but I'd love to know if there's a better way.

**Update:  It turns out that any automated access to Google that doesn't use their new API https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview violates their terms of service, and is thus not recommended.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is still [a free API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview), but here is a screen-scraper:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Get Google Count.')
parser.add_argument('word', help='word to count')
args = parser.parse_args()

r = requests.get('http://www.google.com/search',
                 params={'q':'"'+args.word+'"',
                         "tbs":"li:1"}
                )

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
print soup.find('div',{'id':'resultStats'}).text
```

Results:

```
$ python g.py jones
About 223,000,000 results
$ python g.py smith
About 325,000,000 results
$ python g.py 'smith and jones'
About 54,200,000 results
$ python g.py 'alias smith and jones'
About 181,000 results
```

Comment: Oddly I'm getting a 404 error when I try this, even though I can load the search URL just fine in my browser:

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">

<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /search was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat) Server at www.google.com Port 80</address>
</hr></body></html>
`

Comment: There is, but if I'm getting a 404, I'm getting through the proxy.  There's a different error I get when I don't get through the proxy.

Comment: The thing is, that's not Google's 404 page. Their 404 page has Google branding,  the phrase "That's all we know.", and doesn't mention Apache or Red Hat. I'm afraid I can't help you further, except to point a finger at your proxy setup.

Comment: I did notice that it's different than Google's standard 404 page.

Comment: Indeed it was proxy-related, and this answer helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287628/proxies-with-python-requests-module

Comment: This now works for me, except that I'm searching for a quoted string, and if it gets no hits, it's giving me the number of hits for the unquoted version, which I do not want.  Is there another parameter I can add to the google search url to tell it not to do that?

Comment: Alternately I guess I could just scrape the results for the `No results found for "xyzzy and lmnop"` line in the page returned

Comment: That params line doesn't help.

Comment: also any hints on appropriate delays to avoid being captcha blocked?

Comment: Nope, I can't help you on captcha.

Comment: As of Oct 2022 the div `id` changed so it is now `soup.find('div', {'id':'result-stats'}).text`.