# How to send http request without scheme in python?

Tags: python

```
enUrl='res.iweshow.com'
sr = requests.get(enUrl)
print(sr)
```

When i send http request using requests module in python, here is the traceback:

```
raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for
```

Comment: Why can't you prepend `http://` in your URL?

Comment: @metatoaster sometime you might not no if it's a http or https

Comment: Then how do you expect the library you are using to know?

Comment: What do you mean "might not know". If you're sending the request, don't you know which kind of request you want to make?

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to use HTTP, as indicated in the question, then the answer is simply "add the HTTP scheme in".

Use [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) to easily check if the scheme is absent from the url.

In the case of a proxy, the default scheme is now http [see here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests)
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287628/proxies-with-python-requests-module)