# Python - Use Array of Proxies to Connect to URL?

Tags: python, arrays, sockets, proxy, proxies

So I have been working on a script to check some internal tools we use in our office that are supposed to give an accurate number of users connected to a certain webpage in real time. So far I have built out a code that imports a list of proxies, checks to see which are active, removes duplicates from the list

```
useproxies = set(activeproxylist)
```

And now I want to take that array and have it create a socket connection with the specific URL.

I need a unique IP Address for each connection so I'm not sure if Socks in the way to go on this.

I know how to create a socket connection but using an array of proxies to connect and maintain that connection has me lost. I already have the proxies and have tested them now I just need to be able to use them.

Any guidance on this would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proxies with Python 'Requests' module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287628/proxies-with-python-requests-module)