# python requests fails when using proxy behind a router

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests, router

My code is like this:

```
import requests
proxies = {'http':'ip:port'}
r = requests.get('http://example.com', proxies = proxies)
```

And when I run this code in a PC **with a unique ip address**, it works fine, 
BUT when I run this code in a PC **behind a router**, it cannot get any response.
After I check the proxy server, I find out that the connection was not in the log of the proxy server.

I cannot figure this out, please help, thanks a lot.

With @MilkeyMouse's help, I changed my code to:

```
proxies = {'http':'http://ip:port'}
```

But it still doesn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287628/proxies-with-python-requests-module

Answer (score 0):

Since Requests 2.0.0, you'll need to add a scheme to the proxy. See [the section in the Requests docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies):

```
import requests

proxies = {
  "http": "http://10.10.1.10:3128",
  "https": "http://10.10.1.10:1080",
}

requests.get("http://example.org", proxies=proxies)
```

Note the `http://` before the proxy URL.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I tried this but it still doesn't work.