# Python requests doesn't load site content anymore

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using requests module to retrieve content from the website [kat.cr](http://kat.cr)
and here is the code I used:

```
try:
    response = requests.get('http://kat.cr')
    response.raise_for_status()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
else:
    return response.text
```

At first the code works just fine and I could retrieve the website source code, but then it stopped and I keep receiving this message "404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://kat.cr"

I tried fixing this issue with user-agent like this:

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

try:
    ua = UserAgent()
    ua.update()
    headers = {'User-Agent': ua.random}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
else:
    return response.text
```

But this doesn't seem to work either

Can you please help me fix this problem and thanks.

Comment: I copied your code and ran it 1000 times. Always got a 200 back.

Comment: Same here.  Did they block your ip as a rate limit or something?

Comment: Same here, works just fine. Try opening this url in browser or use different tool - like curl:
curl -L kat.cr

Comment: Your code uses `http:`, but your reported error message has `https:`.  Which is it supposed to be?

Comment: It worked for me too at the first day, but then it just stopped, and it works in the browser too, so I don't think they blocked my IP

Comment: When dealing with torrent sites anything is possible

Answer (score 0):

I think that, as users suggested, you may be ip-blocked.

Try a proxy.

[Proxies with Python 'Requests' module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287628/proxies-with-python-requests-module)