# Python: how to use lots of proxies in module REQUESTS

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I have some difficulties with module `requests`.
It takes argument `proxies`.
I saw in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287628/proxies-with-python-requests-module) description on this module and I've understood, that it takes only one proxy from the dict.
But if one proxy is blocked? 
I want to use dictionary with a lot of proxies, if one proxy is blocked, I want take another proxy, but how can I do that?

Comment: You are going to quickly run out of proxies, you may find using selenium with PhantomJs is a better option

Answer (score 0):

Define `list_of_proxies = [{proxy_0}, {proxy_1}, ...]` and then paste them as needed `r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies = list_of_proxies[i])` where you set `i` according to the logic of your code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll try it soon

Answer (score 0):

Define `list of proxies` and then use `random.choice(list)` function to call random choice from list and use in your code.

Thank you.