# What does requests do with a proxyDict?

Tags: python, python-2.7, proxy, python-requests

I need an explanation on what requests does with a proxyDict, specifically the following:

**1. Does it evenly cycle through all of the proxies in the dictionary?**

**2. What happens if one of them goes down, will requests be able to handle it, or do I have to?**

**3. What happens if one gets "banned", will it handle it?**

**4. If I make a get call in a function, will it still cycle through the proxies evenly?**

So if I have a dictionary of proxies like so:

```
proxyDict = { 
    'https' : 'https://IP1:PORT', 
    'https' : 'https://IP2:PORT', 
    'https' : 'https://IP3:PORT',
    'https' : 'https://IP4:PORT'
}
```

And I have a get request:

```
s = requests.Session()
data = {"Username":"user", "Password":"pass"}
s.get(download_url, proxies = proxyDict, verify=False)
```

Which might be in a function, similarly to this *(my question #4)*:

```
 def foo(download_url, proxyDict, s):
    s.get(download_url, proxies = proxyDict, verify=False)
```

**Also is there any way to print which proxy is currently in use?**

Comment: That dictionary obviosuly won't work, you are assigning multiple values to the same key in different lines.

Comment: @mu無 oops, its just an example used to give context to my question

Comment: Hmm I see. I was in the middle of writing an answer, but now this seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/8287628/1860929

Comment: @mu無 I read the article, but that does not answer any of my specific questions

Comment: It really seems as if a few simple tests would answers most of your questions.

Comment: @larsks I've been testing as best I can. I've been reading the docs on requests and there isn't anything on how to show the last proxy used. So I can't test if the proxies cycle. Also I don't have any banned IP's, and I don't have the power to "turn off" one of our proxies

Comment: @larsks I just thought of a better question. "How do you tell which proxy was used last with python requests?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will find that the keys in your `proxyDict` are supposed to be protocols (like `http` or `https`), and that `requests` will simply ignore your proxies with keys like `http1`, etc.

If you enable `DEBUG` logging, you can see what proxy `requests` is using.  Consider this initial request without proxies:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.basicConfig(level='DEBUG')
>>> requests.get('http://google.com')
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): google.com
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://google.com:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 219
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): www.google.com
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://www.google.com:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4796
<Response [200]>
```

Now, let's set up a proxy dictionary:

```
>>> proxyDict={'http': 'http://squid.corp.example.com:3128'}
```

And re-issue the request using that dictionary:

```
>>> requests.get('http://google.com', proxies=proxyDict)
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): squid.corp.example.com
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://squid.corp.example.com:3128 "GET http://google.com/ HTTP/1.1" 301 219
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://squid.corp.example.com:3128 "GET http://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4768
<Response [200]>
```

You can see in the `DEBUG` messages that it is using the proxy rather than making a direct connection.  Now if we use your proxy dictionary and make the same request...

```
>>> proxyDict = { 
...     'https1' : 'https://IP1:PORT', 
...     'https2' : 'https://IP2:PORT', 
...     'https3' : 'https://IP3:PORT',
...     'https4' : 'https://IP4:PORT'
... }
>>> requests.get('http://google.com', proxies=proxyDict)
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): google.com
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://google.com:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 219
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): www.google.com
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://www.google.com:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4790
<Response [200]>
```

...you can see that it doesn't use any proxies.

Comment: So weird, I guess my program wasn't using a proxy when I set up the proxyDict, which leads to the question, "Why do so many other questions related to proxies and requests use a proxyDict in their answer?" I should just use a list of proxies and cycle through them myself lol

Comment: Random question, using DEBUG, what would one of the lines look like if a proxy server was used?

Comment: You mean like in the answer here, just before "You can see in the DEBUG messages that it is using the proxy..."?

Answer (score 0):

*1. Does it evenly cycle through all of the proxies in the dictionary?*
No it does not. `proxies` is a dictionary with protocols and proxies, `requests` uses the proxy that mathes the protocol of the request (if any).

*2. What happens if one of them goes down, will requests be able to handle it, or do I have to?*
If a proxy is not avaliable for some reason `requests` will raise an exception, you could catch it.

*3. What happens if one gets "banned", will it handle it?*
No, but you could detect an ip ban if you check the status code and response body.

*4. If I make a get call in a function, will it still cycle through the proxies evenly?*
No it won't, see 1.  However you could create a list of proxies and loop over it.

An example:

```
def next_proxy(current):
    '''Returns the next item in proxies.'''
    if not proxies:
        return None
    if current not in proxies or current == proxies[-1]:
        return proxies[0]
    return proxies[proxies.index(current)+1]

def bad_response(response, error_message='some message'):
    '''Detects ip ban and other bad responses.'''
    return response.status_code == 403 or error_message in response.text

proxies = [
    {'https':'https://177.131.51.155:53281', 'http':'http://177.131.51.155:53281'}, 
    {'https':'https://138.197.45.196:8118', 'http':'http://138.197.45.196:8118'}, 
    {'https':'https://153.146.159.139:8080', 'http':'http://153.146.159.139:8080'}, 
]

s = requests.Session()
proxy = None
for _ in range(10):
    print("Using proxy:", proxy)
    try: 
        r = s.get("http://jsonip.com/", proxies=proxy)
        print(r.text)
        if bad_response(r):
            print("bad response")
            #proxies.remove(proxy)
    except (requests.exceptions.ProxyError, requests.exceptions.ConnectionError):
        print("proxy error")
        proxies.remove(proxy)
    proxy = next_proxy(proxy)
```