# How do I open several webpages on the same machine, each with their own proxy?

Tags: javascript, python, proxy, web

I don't really know where to start with this. I need help figuring out how to do this as lightweight as possible. I could rent a server but I would prefer a solution where I don't have to. I am experienced with Python and Javscript. Can these be used?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proxies with Python 'Requests' module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287628/proxies-with-python-requests-module)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, we expect question to have certain information to be valid. For Instance the problem is poorly explained and does not provide code you wrote. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to provide relevant information,

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't provide a lot of technical info to go with.
Therefore, I will provide an High level answer.

Assuming you are using `chrome` as your `webpage`. Than is possible to open multiple instances of chrome with a proxy flag `--proxy-server="foopy:8080"`.

The same high level solution could be achieved with multiple browsers and libs..

Your experience with javascript might help, you can use puppeter & chrome for exactly that.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ 
                  args : [   
                     '--proxy-server="foopy:8080"'
                  ]});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

  await browser.close();
})();
```