# Scraping images from websites without getting HTTP errors

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following list of websites:

```
list_websites=["http://news.m.istella.it/cluster?originalClust…","https://www.optimagazine.com/2020/03/25/"," https://www.playhitmusic.it/2020/03/","https://www.zazoom.it/2020-03-26/","https://oggiscienza.it/2015/11/17/","https://www.msn.com/it-it/video/amici/italias-...","https://www.quotidiano.net"]
```

and I would like to scrape images that might be in each of those urls. As you will be able to see, most of them are not available and/or they have no images. 
The problem is in avoiding to get `HTTP errors` (for example `404` and `403`) just skipping that url (maybe adding into a new list where I could save the 'exceptions' in order to keep track of them). For each website I should save the images into a folder for eventually next use.

I have tried with the following code:

```
images=[]


for link in list_websites:
    html = urlopen(link)
    bs = bs4(html, 'html.parser')
    images = bs4.find_all('img')

    for image in images: 
            images.append(image['src'])
```

but this gives me `HTTP Errors` and interrupt the process of collecting images. 
For example, I know that `HTTP Error 403` means that the server is actively denying me access to files (either I have exceeded a rate-limit, or I am not logged in), but since I have a longer list than that one mentioned above and I will not be able to look at the whole list of websites (3000), I would like to implement in the code a condition that would just skip the websites that are not found or that deny access.

Do you have any idea and/or tips on how I could avoid the process ending and let the program continue to scrape images for the remaining websites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use python **requests** module and check the `status code` of each **url** request.

If `res.status_code==200:` then go and check images.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
list_websites=["http://news.m.istella.it/cluster?originalClust…","https://www.optimagazine.com/2020/03/25/"," https://www.playhitmusic.it/2020/03/","https://www.zazoom.it/2020-03-26/","https://oggiscienza.it/2015/11/17/","https://www.msn.com/it-it/video/amici/italias-...","https://www.quotidiano.net"]

listimages=[]
for link in list_websites:
    res=requests.get(link)
    if res.status_code==200:
        print(link)
        bs = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
        images =bs.find_all('img')

        for image in images:
            listimages.append(image['src'])

print(listimages)
```

**Output**:

```
https://www.optimagazine.com/2020/03/25/
 https://www.playhitmusic.it/2020/03/
https://www.zazoom.it/2020-03-26/
https://oggiscienza.it/2015/11/17/
https://www.quotidiano.net
["data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20viewBox='0%200%20122%2082'%3E%3C/svg%3E", 'https://www.optimagazine.com/wp-content/themes/Optimagazine/img/OM-logo.svg', "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20viewBox='0%200%2032%2032'%3E%3C/svg%3E", 'https://www.optimagazine.com/wp-content/themes/Optimagazine/img/search.png', "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20viewBox='0%200%20355%20202'%3E%3C/svg%3E", 'https://www.optimagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/elton-john-concerto-coronavirus-600x342.jpg', "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20viewBox='0%200%20355%20199'%3E%3C/svg%3E", 'https://www.optimagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/new-amsterdam2_canale5-600x338.jpg', "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20viewBox='0%200%20355%20199'%3E%3C/svg%3E", 'https://www.optimagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/FullMetalJacketDeluxeEdition_85391186274_2-600x338.png', "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20viewBox='0%200%20355%20202'%3E%3C/svg%3E", 'https://www.optimagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/16-novembre-2015-600x342.jpg', "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20viewBox='0%200%20355%20199'%3E%3C/svg%3E", 'https://www.optimagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/adriana_volpe_grande_fratello_vip-600x338.jpg', "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20viewBox='0%200%20355%20199'%3E%3C/svg%3E", 'https://www.optimagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/maltese_il_romanzo_del_commissario-600x338.jpg', "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20viewBox='0%200%20355%20200'%3E%3C/svg%3E", 'https://www.optimagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Chris-Evans-e1585156675446-600x339.jpeg', "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20viewBox='0%200%20355%20199'%3E%3C/svg%3E", 'https://www.optimagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/video-di-amici-per-errore-di-tiziano-ferro-600x338.jpg', "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20viewBox='0%200%20355%20199'%3E%3C/svg%3E", 'https://www.optimagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/televoto-amici-600x338.jpg', "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20viewBox='0%200%20355%20198'%3E%3C/svg%3E", 'https://www.optimagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/iorestoacasamonina-con-noemi-600x335.jpg', "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20viewBox='0%200%20355%20201'%3E%3C/svg%3E", 'https://www.optimagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Huawei-10-600x341.jpg', "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20viewBox='0%200%20355%20177'%3E%3C/svg%3E", 'https://www.optimagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/migliori-giochi-per-Nintendo-3DS-600x300.png', "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20viewBox='0%200%200%200'%3E%3C/svg%3E", 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/c-yhzIG06Wg/sddefault.jpg', "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20viewBox='0%200%20100%200'%3E%3C/svg%3E", 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/qx6lgKrdB20/mqdefault.jpg', "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20viewBox='0%200%20100%200'%3E%3C/svg%3E", 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5kRahPgmAuU/mqdefault.jpg', "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20viewBox='0%200%20100%200'%3E%3C/svg%3E", 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ROAWi3UsV5o/mqdefault.jpg', "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20viewBox='0%200%200%200'%3E%3C/svg%3E", 'https://www.optimagazine.com/wp-content/themes/Optimagazine/img/loading.gif', 'https://www.playhitmusic.it/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/logo-10.png', 'https://www.playhitmusic.it/spot/logo-radio-ita.png', 'https://www.playhitmusic.it/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Wright-1-300x202.jpg', 'https://www.playhitmusic.it/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Alamo_d4ed5fdd2c9e99d6229f6e61dc1accd9-300x202.jpg', 'https://www.playhitmusic.it/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Svezia2-300x224.jpg', 'https://www.playhitmusic.it/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/5e7cbcb5aafb3.image_-300x202.jpg', 'https://www.playhitmusic.it/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/picard-300x202.jpg', 'https://www.playhitmusic.it/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/3600298-bb1-300x202.jpg', 'https://www.playhitmusic.it/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/spenserconfidential-300x202.jpg', 'https://www.playhitmusic.it/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/james-corden-home-fest-e1585687004733-300x169.jpg', 'https://www.playhitmusic.it/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/13th-Floor-Elevators-e1585685334249-300x168.jpg', 'https://www.playhitmusic.it/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/elliot-300x202.jpg', 'https://www.playhitmusic.it/wp-content/themes/pin-wp/images/no-img.png', 'https://www.playhitmusic.it/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/tt4-1-300x165.jpg', 'https://www.playhitmusic.it/wp-content/themes/pin-wp/images/no-img.png', 'https://www.playhitmusic.it/wp-content/themes/pin-wp/images/no-img.png', 'https://www.playhitmusic.it/wp-content/themes/pin-wp/images/no-img.png', 'https://www.playhitmusic.it/wp-content/themes/pin-wp/images/no-img.png', 'https://www.playhitmusic.it/wp-content/themes/pin-wp/images/no-img.png', 'https://www.playhitmusic.it/wp-content/themes/pin-wp/images/no-img.png', 'https://www.playhitmusic.it/wp-content/themes/pin-wp/images/no-img.png', 'https://www.playhitmusic.it/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/ROUAMIHAELA-1200x1200-300x165.jpg', 'https://www.playhitmusic.it/wp-content/themes/pin-wp/images/no-img.png', 'https://www.playhitmusic.it/wp-content/themes/pin-wp/images/no-img.png', 'https://www.zazoom.it/zoom/images/icozoom/29.png', 'https://www.zazoom.it/blog_rsc/images/ajax-loading.gif', 'https://www.zazoom.it/blogs/wp-content/themes/litepress/images/icons/facebook.png', 'https://www.zazoom.it/blogs/wp-content/themes/litepress/images/icons/twitter.png', 'https://www.zazoom.it/blogs/wp-content/themes/litepress/images/icons/googleplus.png', 'https://www.zazoom.it/blogs/wp-content/themes/litepress/images/icons/rss.png', 'https://www.zazoom.it/zoom/images/icon/iphone.png', 'https://www.zazoom.it/logo-red.png', 'https://oggiscienza.it/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/logo_medio.png', 'https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=351342455644616&ev=PageView&noscript=1', 'https://oggiscienza.it/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/logo_piccolo.png', 'https://i0.wp.com/oggiscienza.it/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/cern-higgs.png?resize=540%2C370&ssl=1', 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/f42cf1e5e069398d0d4cd54a1911fb72?s=22&d=identicon&r=g', 'https://i1.wp.com/oggiscienza.it/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/21852146589_56343ca04d_z.jpg?resize=540%2C370&ssl=1', 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/744895a247bf18f5256c44ea008c283c?s=22&d=identicon&r=g', 'https://i2.wp.com/oggiscienza.it/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/13042792905_269d871db0_z.jpg?resize=540%2C370&ssl=1', 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/e833c82a0f1948a8c166a3628bc72c6e?s=22&d=identicon&r=g', 'https://i1.wp.com/oggiscienza.it/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/6889837660_ec2b955731_z.jpg?resize=540%2C370&ssl=1', 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/27fa13772e19287d45eceeac5f672243?s=22&d=identicon&r=g', 'https://i0.wp.com/oggiscienza.it/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/cavalli-probiotici-prebiotici.jpg?resize=540%2C370&ssl=1', 'https://i1.wp.com/oggiscienza.it/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/giornata-mondiale-talassemia.jpg?resize=110%2C85&ssl=1', 'https://i0.wp.com/oggiscienza.it/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/coproliti.jpg?resize=110%2C85&ssl=1', 'https://i2.wp.com/oggiscienza.it/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/solitudine-bates-corner.png?resize=110%2C85&ssl=1', 'https://i0.wp.com/oggiscienza.it/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/vaccini_e_autismo.jpg?resize=110%2C85&ssl=1', 'https://i1.wp.com/oggiscienza.it/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/einstein_-_panini_9l_71477.jpg?resize=110%2C85&ssl=1', 'https://i2.wp.com/oggiscienza.it/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/vespa_velutina.jpg?resize=110%2C85&ssl=1', 'https://i2.wp.com/oggiscienza.it/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/vaccination-1215279_1280-1.jpg?resize=110%2C85&ssl=1', 'https://i0.wp.com/oggiscienza.it/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/cavalli-probiotici-prebiotici.jpg?resize=110%2C85&ssl=1', 'https://i1.wp.com/oggiscienza.it/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/giornata-mondiale-talassemia.jpg?resize=110%2C85&ssl=1', 'https://i0.wp.com/oggiscienza.it/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/coproliti.jpg?resize=110%2C85&ssl=1', 'https://i0.wp.com/oggiscienza.it/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/vaccini_e_autismo.jpg?resize=110%2C85&ssl=1', 'https://i1.wp.com/oggiscienza.it/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/einstein_-_panini_9l_71477.jpg?resize=110%2C85&ssl=1', 'https://i2.wp.com/oggiscienza.it/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/vespa_velutina.jpg?resize=110%2C85&ssl=1', 'https://i2.wp.com/oggiscienza.it/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/vaccination-1215279_1280-1.jpg?resize=110%2C85&ssl=1', 'https://oggiscienza.it/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/footer.png', 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=', 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=', 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=', 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=', 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5142244.1589043813%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Fcinemascope%2Fimage.jpg&w=98&h=42', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5142073.1589038519%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Fcinemascope%2Fimage.jpg&w=66&h=28', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5142391.1589048455%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Fcinemascope%2Fimage.jpg&w=66&h=28', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5141937.1589028490%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Fcinemascope%2Fimage.jpg&w=66&h=28', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5142420.1589050432%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.JPG_gen%2Fderivatives%2Fwidescreen%2Fimage.JPG&w=33&h=18', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.4004785.1530293505%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Fwidescreen%2Fimage.jpg&w=33&h=18', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5142042.1589033438%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Fcinemascope%2Fimage.jpg&w=66&h=28', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5142260.1589044570%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Fcinemascope%2Fimage.jpg&w=66&h=28', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5142190.1589041673%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Fwidescreen%2Fimage.jpg&w=33&h=18', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5142077.1589036184%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Fcinemascope%2Fimage.jpg&w=66&h=28', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5141524.1589006789%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Fcinemascope%2Fimage.jpg&w=66&h=28', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5141643.1589010809%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Fcinemascope%2Fimage.jpg&w=66&h=28', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5141145.1589002125%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Fcinemascope%2Fimage.jpg&w=66&h=28', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5142512.1589054931%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Fcinemascope%2Fimage.jpg&w=66&h=28', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5142066.1589035544%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Fcinemascope%2Fimage.jpg&w=66&h=28', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5141908.1589026910%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Fwidescreen%2Fimage.jpg&w=33&h=18', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5142078.1589036275%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Fwidescreen%2Fimage.jpg&w=33&h=18', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5141584.1589008768%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.JPG_gen%2Fderivatives%2Fwidescreen%2Fimage.JPG&w=33&h=18', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5140420.1589023933%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Fwidescreen%2Fimage.jpg&w=33&h=18', 'https://cdn-static.quotidiano.net/scorpion/5b7d244/img/svg/play.svg', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5141164.1589003796%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Fwidescreen%2Fimage.jpg&w=33&h=18', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5141596.1589008999%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Fwidescreen%2Fimage.jpg&w=33&h=18', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5134061.1589018393%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Fcinemascope%2Fimage.jpg&w=66&h=28', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5141726.1589016432%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Fcinemascope%2Fimage.jpg&w=66&h=28', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5141714.1589015760%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Fwidescreen%2Fimage.jpg&w=33&h=18', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5133741%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Fcinemascope%2Fimage.jpg&w=30&h=12&pos=top', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5133878%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Fcinemascope%2Fimage.jpg&w=30&h=12&pos=top', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5133718%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.JPG_gen%2Fderivatives%2Fcinemascope%2Fimage.JPG&w=30&h=12&pos=top', 'https://cdn-static.quotidiano.net/scorpion/5b7d244/img/svg/logo_qn.svg', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.stqn.it%2Fdjangomedia%2Fkcfeeeds%2Fimg%2F20200509%2Faa85aaeb80cf392b19e873ac01406a7a.jpg&w=9&h=9', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.stqn.it%2Fdjangomedia%2Fkcfeeeds%2Fimg%2F20200509%2Fbf47fe87ee812240725aa213eb35a455.jpg&w=9&h=9', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.stqn.it%2Fdjangomedia%2Fkcfeeeds%2Fimg%2F20200509%2Fd5ae00615f385597d81240600dbbb41f.png&w=9&h=9', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.stqn.it%2Fdjangomedia%2Fkcfeeeds%2Fimg%2F20200509%2F7b7a4d9784c9093947acac56d63b178a.jpg&w=9&h=9', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.stqn.it%2Fdjangomedia%2Fkcfeeeds%2Fimg%2F20200509%2F2ff3bf5f3ad1786f551468281305ec88.jpg&w=9&h=9', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.stqn.it%2Fdjangomedia%2Fkcfeeeds%2Fimg%2F20200509%2F3734d858032fd83373b080392f6e3824.jpg&w=9&h=9', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.stqn.it%2Fdjangomedia%2Fkcfeeeds%2Fimg%2F20200509%2F11a082bfe21618bb8cffb1951ca72f84.jpg&w=9&h=9', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.stqn.it%2Fdjangomedia%2Fkcfeeeds%2Fimg%2F20200509%2F0377035938989686135090a4b02e3d16.jpg&w=9&h=9', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.stqn.it%2Fdjangomedia%2Fkcfeeeds%2Fimg%2F20200509%2F28cef96f952558b015eed2496da58fc6.jpg&w=9&h=9', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.quotidiano.net%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5142512%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Fwide_680%2Fimage.jpg&w=30&h=12&pos=top', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.quotidiano.net%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5142107%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Fwide_680%2Fimage.jpg&w=30&h=12&pos=top', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.quotidiano.net%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5142177%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Fwide_680%2Fimage.jpg&w=30&h=12&pos=top', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.quotidiano.net%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5142273%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Fwide_680%2Fimage.jpg&w=30&h=12&pos=top', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.quotidiano.net%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.4715646!%2Fmenu%2Fstandard%2Ffile%2F300x250_personali.gif&w=30', 'https://www.quotidiano.net/polopoly_fs/1.5139022.1588858923!/menu/standard/file/Osservatorio-08-05-2020.gif', 'https://www.quotidiano.net/polopoly_fs/1.4885707.1573735772!/menu/standard/file/Webp.net-gifmaker%20%281%29.gif', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5136223.1588687022%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Ffullsize%2Fimage.jpg&w=30&h=25', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5070563.1584371797%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Ffullsize%2Fimage.jpg&w=30&h=25', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5070541.1584370904%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Ffullsize%2Fimage.jpg&w=30&h=25', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.5070561.1584371718%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Ffullsize%2Fimage.jpg&w=30&h=25', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.4427194.1549376454%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Ffullsize%2Fimage.jpg&w=30&h=25', 'https://immagini.quotidiano.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fp1014p.quotidiano.net%3A80%2Fpolopoly_fs%2F1.4380199.1546870149%21%2FhttpImage%2Fimage.jpg_gen%2Fderivatives%2Ffullsize%2Fimage.jpg&w=30&h=25']
```

Answer (score 0):

403 Forbidden – you don’t have permission to access
That's meen you can not get html file from this url.
You can try use proxy

[Proxies with Python 'Requests' module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287628/proxies-with-python-requests-module)