# Proxy server doesn't change public IP with Python Requests

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I'm running this script:

```
import requests

proxyDict = {"http"  : 'http://81.93.73.28:8081'}

r = requests.get('http://ipinfo.io/ip', proxies=proxyDict)
r.status_code
r.headers['content-type']

r.encoding

print(r.text)
```

I've tried my own proxy server as well as several public servers. It still prints my current ip.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proxies with Python 'Requests' module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287628/proxies-with-python-requests-module)

Comment: no, my script is based on those answers. Doesn't work for some reason. Probably just a newbie mistake, i barely know python

Comment: @sktvlfw can you accept my answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems seem to be with proxy. I tried the random, free one with that code. Also, your code got a few issues. You are calling attributes without usage - they are no need. Try with that code and proxy, for me, it worked.

```
proxyDict = {"http"  : 'http://162.14.18.11:80'}

r = requests.get('http://ipinfo.io/ip', proxies=proxyDict, )
print(r.status_code)

print(r.text)
```