# i'm trying to get product information using BeautifulSoup, but unable to get the text between <span> </span>

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
def Bprice2(url):
    print("Fetching details....")
    response=requests.get(url)
    detail=response.content
    soup=BeautifulSoup(detail,'html.parser')
    name=soup.find('span',{'class':'a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal'}).text
    print(str(name))
    
URL2='https://www.amazon.in/s?k=iphone+11'
bestprice2=Bprice2(URL2)
```

**this is the error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\Users\91858\Desktop\py auto\bestprice.py", line 37, in <module>
    bestprice2=Bprice2(URL2)
   File "c:\Users\91858\Desktop\py auto\bestprice.py", line 32, in Bprice2
    name=soup.find('span',{'class':'a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal'}).text 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: In short, `soup.find(...)` returned `None`, i.e. has not found anything.

Comment: Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63305902/why-cant-i-scrape-amazon-products-by-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `headers` to you `requests` call so you will able to find data easily.

```
import requests
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers={"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}
res=requests.get("https://www.amazon.in/s?k=iphone+11",headers=headers)
soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
name=soup.find("span",class_="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal").get_text()
```

Output:

```
'Apple iPhone 11 (128GB) - White'
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.