# How to translate cURL command to Python request

Tags: python, api, curl, https, proxy

I can't figure this out for the life of me.

`curl Command: curl --proxy-negotiate -u : <API_PATH> -H "Authorization: Bearer <token> " -H "Accept: application/scim+json"`

This command works, but only after I run this command: set HTTPS_PROXY <corporate_Proxy_Path> , or
it if I do this by editing env variables in windows settings.

in Python, I am doing this as the equivalent.

````
endpoint = <API_PATH>
headers = {"Authorization": B"earer <token> ", "Accept": "application/scim+json"

print(requests.get(endpoint, headers)```


I keep getting this proxy error: Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSERROR('Tunnel connections failed: 407 Proxy Authentication required."
````

Comment: did u check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287628/proxies-with-python-requests-module?

Comment: https://curl.trillworks.com/