# pd.read_html works in Microsoft Edge but not in Chrome

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

This simple code works in Microsoft Edge but not in Chrome (both using Jupyter):

```
import pandas as pd
url_Chelsea = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Chelsea_F.C._seasons"

df_Chelsea=pd.read_html(url_Chelsea)[2]
df_Chelsea
```

getting the error message (end of message):

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py in raise_with_traceback(exc, traceback)
    338         if traceback == Ellipsis:
    339             _, _, traceback = sys.exc_info()
--> 340         raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
    341 else:
    342     # this version of raise is a syntax error in Python 3

URLError: <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tested with some other links? like other Wikipedia article also? Is this same for all other link?

Comment: Yes, I have tried for the 4 London clubs: Chelsea, Tottenham, Arsenal and Fulham and same problem, thanks

Comment: Are you using proxy?

Comment: Not really familiar with these technologies, so can't tell

Comment: Write this : I am getting this error message by inplementing your answer @Xitiz :
<>
[edit] from here

Comment: Just few seconds, getting message: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details. So cannot submit. Can I submit just the plain text? will not be easy to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url_Chelsea = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Chelsea_F.C._seasons"
proxyDict = { 
          'http'  : "add http proxy", 
          'https' : "add https proxy"
        }

requests.get(url_Chelsea , proxies=proxyDict)

df_Chelsea=pd.read_html(page)[2]
print(df_Chelsea)
```

For more information about `proxies` visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287628/proxies-with-python-requests-module)

Comment: Without some more information i can't tell you, you should do this to solve your problem but anyway try this and inform .

Comment: Get a different error message. Last line:
                                              ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='en.wikipedia.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /wiki/List_of_Chelsea_F.C._seasons (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden',)))

Comment: Complete error message is too long to put in a comment (600 characters max)

Comment: I have commented in question follow that. :)

Comment: @Alan I hadn't notice that you have edited the comment. You are using proxy. follow last edit of answer.

Comment: Running last edit of answer gives the same error message which is now shown as added pictures in the edited post, please see

Comment: I have edited just few second ago. I don't think you implemented that.

Comment: I still get an error message, not the same. Last 3 lines:
ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='en.wikipedia.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /wiki/List_of_Chelsea_F.C._seasons (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f58099c7550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)))

Comment: I believe you have added that `add http proxy` part with proxy, right?

Comment: The proxyDict? Yes I did. 
For line df_Chelsea=pd.read_html(page)[2], shouldn't it be url instead of page?

Comment: You can, that is just the name. Is that error occurring in both browser?

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time @Xitiz, really appreciate. I will just have to work with Edge when dealing with this pandas read_html function. Best