# Web Traffic Increaser : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, request

im beginner on programming,so i wrote a program for increase web traffic.(Ofcourse for ethic experiments) But when ever i run this program,i keep getting same error.So if you can help me , thank you.i thinks thats something about write problems but i couldn't find which one when i look to the results.if you want all script,i can share it but for now beacuse of thats too long i cant share.Thanks for helping.

-Sorry for bad english

[Here my code:][2]

```
def sending():
        for i in range(1,50):
            
            c = random.choice(ConProx)
            if is_bad_proxy(c):
                sending()
            else:
                    proxies2 = {
            'http':('http://'+c),
            'https':('https://'+c),
            }
            url = "https://www.etsy.com/shop/AlprnDesign"
            requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=ConProx, verify=False)
            print(url+""+"adresine"+""+c+""+"Ip adresiyle gönderim yapıldı")
            time.sleep(5)

sending()

  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPfSO.png
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* (not images) **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mre].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). To show your error message, copy and paste it out of the terminal window, and format it like code.

Comment: [link Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287628/proxies-with-python-requests-module)  List and dict are different type(on turkish : listelere get işlemi uygulanamaz, sözlük olması gerekir.)  Best regards.