# How would I implement my proxy into a request with http.client?

Tags: python, python-3.x, socks, http.client

```py
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+jtw,
}
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.minecraftservices.com")
conn.request("PUT", "/minecraft/profile/name/"+user, headers=headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
status_code = response.status
resp = response.read().decode("utf-8")
```

^ My code
Because http.client is not used much, I couldn't really find an answer on google. How would I add a proxy to this?

Comment: It is not used much because you are not supposed to use it directly. I recommend using `requests` and here is how you do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287628/proxies-with-python-requests-module

Comment: Oh well, I'm using it of the speed, could I use sockets with proxies? or pycurl? Requests is really too slow

Comment: Well if you really must you can use something like the example here, https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPConnection.set_tunnel