# Python - What other options are there when requests Retry for rate limit error still gives error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

The API docs say the following:

> The overall rate limit is 60 requests per minute. This rate limit
> applies to any combination of API methods that are called within a
> trailing 1-minute timeframe

I'm trying the below that gets a response for each page, but I see the following error:

> "ok": false, "error": "rate_limited" 429 status code

I feel like the backoff_factor isn't working because I have it set to 1 but I see this error after 18seconds of my code running, shouldn't it run for at least 1 minute?

```
def get_request():

   session = requests.Session()
   retry = Retry(total=5, connect=7, backoff_factor=1)
   adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
   session.mount('https://', adapter)

   url = "https://my_url" 

   first_page = session.post(url).json()
   yield first_page
   num_pages = first_page['last_page']
   for page in range(2, num_pages + 1):
       next_page = session.post(url, params={'page': page}).json()
       yield next_page

for page in get_request():
     etc...


   list = []
   for page in range(2, num_pages + 1):
              response = sessions.post(url, params={'page': page}).json()
      r_json = response.json()
      list.append(r_json)
```

Comment: The HTTP rate limit is a server-side configuration and cannot be changed from the client-side.

Comment: @ArtyomVancyan - got it! but what would be the right way to go about working around the rate limit to get the code working?

Comment: Try using proxies

Comment: @ArtyomVancyan - thanks! Do you know of a good resource to learn more about this and some example maybe?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287628/proxies-with-python-requests-module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think it will run for at least 1 minute? As per the [documentation](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.util.html#utilities) for Retry:

> A backoff factor to apply between attempts after the second try (most
> errors are resolved immediately by a second try without a delay).
> urllib3 will sleep for:
>
> {backoff factor} * (2 ** ({number of total retries} - 1)) seconds.
>
> If the backoff_factor is 0.1, then Retry.sleep() will sleep for [0.0s,
> 0.2s, 0.4s, …] between retries. It will never be longer than backoff_max.

You have the `backoff_factor` set to `1`, with the `total` retries set to 5. This means that at most there can be **1 original** + **5 retry** requests sent to the server, if requests receive a 429 error. Going step-by-step, this is how your requests will be made:

- **Original** request sent
- Server returned 429 error, **first retry** made after **0 seconds**
  `1 * (2 ** (1-1))`
- Server returned 429 error, **second retry** made after **2 seconds**
  `1 * (2 ** (2-1))`
- Server returned 429 error, **third retry** made after **4 seconds**
  `1 * (2 ** (3-1))`
- Server returned 429 error, **fourth retry** made after **8 seconds**
  `1 * (2 ** (4-1))`
- Server returned 429 error, **fifth retry** made after **16 seconds**
  `1 * (2 ** (5-1))`

This gives a total of at least **30 seconds** for which your code will wait before raising an error (excluding latencies). It is possible that you made a mistake in calculating how long the your program runs before an exception is raised (i.e. it ran for more than 18s), and it is also possible that the server enforces a lower limit than what is stated, rate-limits can be fickle.

In any case, if you want the program to wait till the rate limit expires (the publicly stated one anyway), then either increase the total retries, or increase the `backoff_factor` (using the formula) so that the total wait time comes larger than `60`.

[Reference](https://majornetwork.net/2022/04/handling-retries-in-python-requests/)