# requests/urllib module not working on company laptop

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

The following get request works on my personal computer:

```
import requests
requests.get('https://example.org')
```

However, the same request on my work laptop results in this error:

```
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', TimeoutError(10060, 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond', None, 10060, None))
```

**What i've tried:**

- 1. Setting up proxy

Based on [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67821799/python-3-requests-get-does-not-work-at-my-company-internet-workaround) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287628/proxies-with-python-requests-module) given, i've tried to set up the proxies using the following code below but it still returned the same error.

```
requests.get('https://example.org',
             proxies=urllib.request.getproxies())
```

However, when I did a check at http://www.whatismyproxy.com/, it says that "no proxies were detected". `urllib.request.getproxies()` also returned a blank dict `{}`

[image]

- 2. Adding SSL cert

Also tried adding SSL cert but still had the same error

```
requests.get('https://example.org',
             proxies=urllib.request.getproxies(),
             verify=requests.certs.where())
```

So I'm not sure what else I can do so that the get request can work on my work laptop.

Comment: Can you access the URL using a browser on your company network? There may be a firewall in place that's blocking certain outbound connections

Comment: @OldBill Yes, I can access it on my company network

Comment: Have you tried another link like google.com on your work computer? maybe python.exe is blocked on firewall settings

Comment: @AliEnt Google works, i've just tried `requests.get('https://www.google.com/')` and it returned `<Response [200]>`, but it doesn't work for the link that i want to access

Comment: Test Google with proxy to make sure the proxy is working

Comment: @Jon Try adding a User-Agent header

Comment: @AliEnt `requests.get('https://www.google.com/', proxies=urllib.request.getproxies())` still works but `urllib.request.getproxies()` returns an empty dict anyway so is there another way to find the proxy ip?

Comment: @OldBill Tried adding `headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}`, works for google but not for other links

Comment: There are some websites that give you free proxies, you can search "free proxy list". but my experience was bad with them, most of them are not working. If you have problem with them you can buy one.

Comment: @Jon Facing the same issue, have u found anything that worked?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this very same issue on my company laptop too.

I needed to execute requests.get() for an intranet (within company) URL.
Simply passing the proxy in the `proxies` argument in the `requests.get()` definition will not work.

For this, you will need to create a **User-level Environment Variable** called `HTTPS_PROXY`, and pass your proxy URL as this variable's value.

This **explicit passing** then takes care to redirect our `requests.get(url)` when we execute it via Python.

Hope it'll work for you, as it did for me :)