# HTTPX | Requests Proxies Setup

Tags: python, proxies, httpx

I am trying to use Proxies for my WebScraping Project, which i did build with HTTPX.
However when i was setting up my proxies i still got blocked, so i tryed out if the actully work/get used. I bought some proxys from an professional website/seller, so they work just fine.

I found a website, which returns the IP, from which i am making the request.
I Tryed to test the USE of proxies like that:

```
import httpx
import requests

#Username:PW:Hostname
proxies = {"http://": "http://username:pw.io:hostname"}


#response = requests.get('http://ipinfo.io/json',proxies=proxies)
response = httpx.get('http://ipinfo.io/json',proxies=proxies)

print(response.text)
```

Both requests and httpx dont work for me, as the response always returns my real IP. How do i need to set up my Proxiex? Keep in mind, that i actually want to use HTTPX and just used requests for debugging aswell.

Comment: `http://` is not a valid protocol value to be passed as a key in the `dict` for the `proxies` keyword argument; seems you meant just `"http"`. This is a duplicate of [Proxies with Python 'Requests' module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287628/proxies-with-python-requests-module)

Answer (score 1):

How about if try to send the request to verify IP address without proxy first (like using WhatIsMyIP tools and other else), and then send the request through proxy

```py
import httpx

proxy_url = "http://username:pw.io:hostname"
proxies = {"http://": proxy_url, "https://": proxy_url}

# Verify our IP address without proxy first to this website
response = httpx.get("https://www.whatismyip.com/")
print("IP address without proxy:", response.text)

# And then we request through proxy
with httpx.Client(proxies=proxies) as client:
    response = client.get("https://www.whatismyip.com/")
    print("IP address with proxy:", response.text)
```

If the proxy is working correctly, the IP address that displayed should be different with the previous one