# Can not get correction response from Flask server when sending data by a proxy

Tags: python, flask, proxy, gunicorn

I created a simple Flask application on my tiny VPS, and started by Gunicorn with a simple command `gunicorn -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:8888 app:app --access-logfile=- --proxy-protocol`.

I tried the code below on my local PC with Python requests

```
import requests
url= 'http://124.202.218.128:5000/new/'
resp = requests.post(url, data=data)
proxies = {'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:7890'}
resp2 = requests.post(url, data=data, proxies=proxies)
```

The `resp` returned a correct data with HTTP code 200, the `resp2` with a proxy get a 502 error code. This proxy `http://127.0.0.1:7890` is valid when I use it in my browser.

How can I update flask or gunicord to receive data from proxied post?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8287752/8353711) answer?

Comment: @shaikmoeed I tried this and returned the same code.

Comment: How are you using the proxy in the browser? Can you elaborate on that in the post?

Comment: @shaikmoeed Thanks for your reply. I used this proxy in my browser on SwitchyOmega Extension. 127.0.0.1:7890 used as a HTTP proxy. This proxy is provided by Clash for Windows. Is it enough for you to figure out?