# How should the requests syntax look with a proxy?

Tags: python, proxy

In python's requests module, when using a proxy to be protected, what actually is that proxy? I know it's something along the lines of an intermediary server that hides your identity or something like that. In the requests module, what should actually go into requests dictionary, and are there any ways I can easily get a proxy server?

I've been looking around for a way to get a proxy into my BS4 web scraping. Currently, I understand the syntax of using a proxy dictionary and referencing that dictionary while using the requests function and whatnot. However, I'm a bit confused on what the proxy actually is. The requests [documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/) only goes so far as to explain the syntax. Additionally, should http/https have different ips regarding the security of the website being scraped?
I currently have:

```py
import requests
proxies = {
     'http': [numbers for something]
     'https': [numbers for something]
url = https://www.britannica.com/
page = requests.get(url, proxies = proxies)
```

Edit:
I've learned a bit more of what the proxy ip actually is. I've tried to get a few, but I think they're wrong because the output is lots of errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proxies with Python 'Requests' module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287628/proxies-with-python-requests-module)